# Concatenate text in Field Value in Database where Fieldvalue is not empty

Tags: mysql

I want to concatenate specific text before existing text in database column, where field value is not empty

For instance - i have column v_small_img - where there are many fields which are blank and some have values

I need to append in text only in fields which have values and not to append text in fields which are blank

I have reached in to this,

```
UPDATE `#_toys_variants` SET v_small_img=CONCAT('images/uploads/variants/',v_small_img);
```

but the code can actually include in 'images/uploads/variants/' in all fields, instead of checking which fields are empty

How to achieve the desired

Comment: Add `WHERE` clause to check if fieldvalue is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the non empty `v_small_img` in `WHERE` clause:

```
UPDATE `#_toys_variants`
SET v_small_img = CONCAT(
    'images/uploads/variants/',
    v_small_img
)
WHERE v_small_img <> ''
```

**Note:**

In order to rollback the empty value in `v_small_img` field which might hold this value `'images/uploads/variants/'` because of your above query :

```
UPDATE `#_toys_variants`
SET v_small_img = ''
WHERE v_small_img = 'images/uploads/variants/'
```

Comment: It's so likely the case :)